# ts-node - how can I configure input/source file location?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, ts-node

I have `TypeScript` and `ts-node` installed globally and have the following files/directories -

```
+tsproject
    +src
        -main.ts
    -tsconfig.json
```

I can compile the `main.ts` file with `tsc src/main.ts` command or execute it directly with `ts-node src/main.ts` command. However, I'd like to use the commands `tsc main.ts` and `ts-node main.ts` instead, while setting some configuration for the path `src` so that the compiler knows where the `main.ts` file is located.

I have tried setting `"rootDir": "src/"` in the `tsconfig.json` file, but it didn't work - basically both commands complain about `main.ts` not being found.

My main purpose would be executing a specific file with `ts-node`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a `tsconfig.json` that specifies an `include` (such as `["src/**/*.ts"]`), then you simply need to run `tsc`, not `tsc main.ts` in order to compile. [Read more about `tsconfig.json` and its settings here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). However, there's no easy way to get `ts-node` to change its root directory. Note that `rootDir` is **not** meant to be the source directory, so `"rootDir": "src/"` can break things or cause inconvenience.

Comment: My main purpose is executing a specific file with `ts-node`. I don't think `include` would help.